# Unable to inject repository in test for spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Unable to Autowired FooRepository, its always set to null

Config.java class

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.foo.repository")
public class Config extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
```

Test class

```
@SpringIntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FooRepositoryTest.ConfigTest.class })
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Configuration
    @Import({ Config.class })
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.repository")
    static class ConfigTest {}

    @Autowired FooRepository repository;
..
}
```

Comment: in which package is the repository?

Comment: what are you testing? Sprign Data Elasticsearch library or an application using it? And you are using JUnit5?

Comment: and sure you're using `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.junit.jupiter.SpringIntegrationTest`?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch package is in the src repository and I am using org.springframework.integration.test.context.SpringIntegrationTest. I am trying to test an application which uses Spring Data Elasticsearch library for access to ES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/test/context/SpringIntegrationTest.html), this is how it is used:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringIntegrationTest
public class MyIntegrationTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

}
```

In your case the annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is missing

Comment: that's a different `@SpringIntegrationTest` annotation probably

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I hope he's testing a Spring Integration project because that does not make sens to use that annotation in another context.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch has an annotation `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.junit.jupiter.SpringIntegrationTest` which is used by the test for the project itself to start a test with a TestContainer and Spring context